# Codeigniter DB Language extension not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, wamp

I'm trying to use [this extension](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Language-Class-Extended-DB)

But it gives me the following error when loading the library:

```
Unable to load the requested class: Language
```

Also if I write MY_Language instead, it gives me the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'CI_Language' not found in C:\wamp\www\ckphp\application\libraries\MY_Language.php on line 79
```

I am using WAMP and CI v. 2.2.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself after some more researching...

Apparently the language class is not even in the library folder, but in core folder, meaning it should be placed in the core application/core folder. Also the name is not CI_Language, but CI_Lang, meaning the file name has to be MY_Lang (if MY_ is your prefix). The last thing to change in the extension is

`parent::CI_Language();`

to

`parent::__construct();`

and everything should work fine!

Usage:

```
$this->lang->load('set', 'language'); // To load a language
$this->lang->line('key'); // to display the text
```

or simply

```
lang('key'); // if using the language helper
```

Hope this will help others in the future!

Comment: You saved me so much trouble. Was looking all around the forums and everybody was extending the CI:Language class. I don't know which version they were running but I was pulling my hairs out. Thanks for solving this problem!

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could help. I was struggling with this aswell, hopefully it will be easier for people to find this solution now :)

Comment: Thanks dude, coming from Laravel, the outdated CI documentation drive me nuts

Answer (score 1):

I made a GIST for latest CodeIgniter 3.1.X including with migration to create the database structure

https://gist.github.com/cyberfly/885b320fdf914ae15f7316b22cc72f32